# Interating through imported json in node.js and express, then displaying with jade

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

After looking at the examples and answers given in related questions here on StackExchange and trying to use them to resolve my issue, I'm finally posting my question. Grrr....

So My goal is to eventually access some complex json via api and REST. I was hoping to import (currently via require but eventually via Oauth'd RESTful API) json, parse it to discover the key/value pairs (including nested keys and values) and then at the very least create an object I could then display and have access to all elements. I hope that's making sense. Anyway, to begin to build that I thought I'd get some example json and require it. Well I initally tried some json from the API that I'm going to use but I'm afraid that it was causing issues (well, my inexperience with node, express and jade is really the cause) so I decided to simplify and grab some very simple json. A colorsArray. So .. now some code. Here's the console output including the error I get after error I get after attempting to render the web page. Please ignore the pathings because I'm using my php oriented Eclipse IDE to run nodeclipse (which is working awesome btw)

```
{ colorsArray: 
   [ { colorName: 'red', hexValue: '#f00' },
     { colorName: 'green', hexValue: '#0f0' },
     { colorName: 'blue', hexValue: '#00f' },
     { colorName: 'cyan', hexValue: '#0ff' },
     { colorName: 'magenta', hexValue: '#f0f' },
     { colorName: 'yellow', hexValue: '#ff0' },
     { colorName: 'black', hexValue: '#000' } ] }
Express server listening on port 3000
```

After some work (with advise from comments and answers below) I'm now getting the following in my browser

```
**Express**

Welcome to Express

[object Object]
```

I've update code in the sections below to reflect advice.

Here's my *current* app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

//Load projects as JSON.
var ob = require('./simple.json');
console.log(ob);

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// set object for templates
app.locals('ob' , ob);

// development only
if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

and *current* index.js

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */


exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' , ob: req.body});
  };
```

index.jade

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  p #{ob}



for(var prop in ob)
 p #{ob.colorName}: #{ob.hexValue}
```

and finally layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
```

ADD-->Initially forgot to add the json file I'm trying to import

```
{
    "colorsArray":[{
            "colorName":"red",
            "hexValue":"#f00"
        },
        {
            "colorName":"green",
            "hexValue":"#0f0"
        },
        {
            "colorName":"blue",
            "hexValue":"#00f"
        },
        {
            "colorName":"cyan",
            "hexValue":"#0ff"
        },
        {
            "colorName":"magenta",
            "hexValue":"#f0f"
        },
        {
            "colorName":"yellow",
            "hexValue":"#ff0"
        },
        {
            "colorName":"black",
            "hexValue":"#000"
        }
    ]
}
```

So there you have it. Again, I'd LOVE to be able to get the json, parse it to identify the elements (including nested sub-elements) and have it as an object I can access for logic and display. But right now, I'd be giddy with being able to just display it in the jade and access the object's elements via a loop.

Thanks for taking time to look through this and I know this has been answered here in other examples but I've spent a week trying to employ those solutions with no luck

Comment: The JSON is invalid => `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`

Comment: That's a JS object, not JSON. Every non-numeric key / value is quoted in JSON

Comment: I added the simple.json file above.

Answer (score 0):

When node.js requires a json file it [automatically parses it](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules). 
You are attempting to parse it a second time here:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  var ob = JSON.parse(ob);
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' , ob: ob});
};
```

Try omitting `JSON.parse` and pass the object straight to the render method.

Comment: now new error ... which is a good thing `ReferenceError: ob is not defined
    at exports.index (/Users/Baci/Documents/php-workspace/pav_test/routes/index.js:9:48)`

Comment: ```ob``` is defined in app.js, not in index.js, so you need to retrieve it from app.locals or rewrite your index file to accept a config object:
e.g:

```exports.index = function(ob){
        return function(ob){
            res.render('index', { title: 'Express' , ob: ob});
        };
    };```

Comment: Well interestingly @benbrunton , your suggestion has caused my browser to hang. Which I consider progress :) in app.js I think I've set ob to locals `app.locals('ob' , ob)` but how to retrieve it in the jade file?

Comment: looking at express documentation you should store ob with ```app.locals.ob = ob;``` and can retrieve it with ```var ob = app.locals.ob;```